# convert multipart form (input type = file) into WordPress media library upload

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, file-upload, media

I'm trying to modify a wordpress plugin and need to decide if it's feasible to tweak the changes I want, or not possible.

### The bad feature I'm trying to fix:

This plugin uses customized posts. When a user creates a new post of this type, there is a button to upload an image. This upload relies on a multipart(input type = file) instead of the media library. I'm trying to intercept this process and stick in a media uploader... then pass the data to the next function as though it were coming from a non-wordpress multi-part form. Tons of functions after this point rely on the data coming in a certain way, which is why I'm trying to mimic the results of a naturally uploaded file.

### Issues I'm stuck on:

- The function called after submit is waiting for $_FILES array data to come in. I'm not sure if it's possible to force my own data (returned from media uploader javascript) into this array
- Even if I could force data into $_FILES, capturing the returned JavaScript values into PHP variables seems like a problem. - I was considering using 'on_submit' and makeing a JS function to populate an HTML input with values...but I can't think of how to easily get those values into the $_FILES afterwards.
- The media Library does use $_FILES array (wordpress core includes/media.php) but those values are null by the time I var_dump in my plugin files.

Comment: What is "media uploader"? Not certain what you are trying to achieve? Can you include `html` , `javascript` tried at Question?

Comment: The media uploader is used when you're in wordpress admin/dasboard of your site and need to add an image /file to the gallery. Many plugins make use of the uploader which can be envoked with JavaScript. As for code, id prefer to hold off since this is a custom plugin for my company. If necessary i can add it, but i think the problem has been generalized to not require code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. [Remove](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) the offending file uploader from within your plugin.

```
add_filter('add_meta_boxes', 'hide_meta_boxes_file_uploader');

function hide_meta_boxes_file_uploader() {

    remove_meta_box('metabox_id', 'custom_post_type', 'context');//edit value accordingly

}
```

Then add your own media uploader as outlined [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/properly-add-an-upload-media-button-in-a-meta-box-field). Just set the field name to the field name of the `meta_box` you removed and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I wound up going a different direction but appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

I realized it was more appropriate to change the code at a different spot. The $_FILE form values were being inserted into the database as a post attachment using wp_insert_attachment.

**Here's what I did**

1. I added my media library uploader code (javascript)
2. collected the returned JS data that would be needed for wp_insert_attachment (specifically: URL, Mime type, title)
3. Appended these values to some hidden inputs in my form (to access them with $_POST array)
4. set wp_insert_attachment equal to collected $_POST values - sending the values to the DB as though it were coming from a regular post.